# Store constants in a file, use for module Instantiation in generate block

Tags: constants, verilog, system-verilog

I am currently trying to implement an fir-filter consisting of N taps. I have written the code for a single tap and want to generate N single taps in the top module.

```
module fir #(
  parameter DataWidthBits = 32,
  parameter N = 3
)(
  ....
);
  genvar gen_i;
  generate
    for (gen_i=0; gen_i<N; gen_i=(gen_i+1)) begin : single_taps
      fir_one_tap #(DataWidthBits, filter_coeffs[i]) fir_one_tap_inst (i_clk, i_resetn, r_sample_delay[gen_i], r_adder[gen_i]);
    end
  endgenerate
```

Each of the taps can be parametrized with DataWidth and a coefficient from `filter_coeffs`. My idea was to read these values from a .csv-file consisting of hex-values like the following

```
0, 1, A
```

This is how I tried reading the file and save the hex values to a `localparam` array:

```
localparam [DataWidthBits-1:0] filter_coeffs [FilterTaps-1:0];
initial begin
    integer coeff_file, scan_ret;
    coeff_file = $fopen("coeffs_hex.csv", "r");
    while (i < FilterTaps) begin
      scan_ret  = $fscanf(coeff_file, "%h", filter_coeffs[i]);
    end
    $fclose(coeff_file);
end
```

While linting, I receive the following error:

```
Parameter without initial value is never given value (IEEE 1800-2017 6.20.1): 'filter_coeffs'
                       : ... note: In instance 'fir_wbs.fir'
   57 |     localparam [DataWidthBits-1:0] [FilterTaps-1:0] filter_coeffs;
```

I suspected that I did write values from the csv file into the `filter_coeffs` array and therefore gave them a value.

Comment: Maybe try it this way [incorporate filter constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78078752/what-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-coefficients-of-a-large-digital-filter-in-ver/78082119#78082119)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is illegal.  You must assign constant values to a `locapram` when you declare it, for example:

```
localparam WIDTH = 5;
```

Constants, like `localparam`, must be assigned **before** simulation begins.  This means they can not be assigned in procedural code (like an `initial` block).

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.20 *Constants*.

---

The standard way to set parameters via an external file is with a `` `include `` file. But, you have the same issue: the include file must contain legal syntax.

You can always use your favorite software language to automatically generate any Verilog code you need and include it with your compiled Verilog files.

---

If Python is used to create coefficients, consider `firwin` or `firwin2` from the package `scipy.signal`.

Comment: When I write the values from the file into a reg instead of a localparam, I receive the error that the values for instantiation have to be constant. %Error: fir/fir.v:90:50: Expecting expression to be constant, but variable isn't const: 'i'
                       : ... note: In instance 'fir_wbs.fir'
   90 |       fir_one_tap #(DataWidthBits, filter_coeffs[i]) fir_one_tap_inst (i_clk, i_resetn, r_sample_delay[gen_i], r_adder[gen_i]);

Comment: Thanks for the update. Maybe this is the way to go then. Use a python-script to create a verilog-file with a constant set of filters and include them into my design. I will accept it as an answer to my question